# British Iranian Dual National travelling to USA

Tags: esta, us-visa-waiver-program, uk-citizens, visa-free-entry, iranian-citizens

I have lived in Scotland (Britain) all of my life and hold a full UK passport. I also have an Iranian passport as both of my parents were brought up there. I have been to Iran a handful of times, most recently in June 2012. I have no stamps on my British passport from when I entered Iran.

I want to go to America for a 2/3 week holiday this year but very confused with the new ESTA rules etc.

Can someone please let me know if they have been in the same situation as me and whether they applied for an ESTA and successfully got given one. Or, if they had to obtain a travel Visa.

Answer (score 16):

You will need to apply for a visa as you have travelled to Iran and you are a national of Iran.

[Link to cbp.gov](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/visa-waiver-program/visa-waiver-program-improvement-and-terrorist-travel-prevention-act-faq)

> Under the Act, travelers in the following categories are no longer eligible to travel or be admitted to the United States, without a waiver, under the VWP:
>
> - Nationals of VWP countries who have traveled to or been present in    Iraq, Syria, Iran, Sudan, Libya, Somalia, or Yemen at any time on or
>     after March 1, 2011 (with limited exceptions); and
> - Nationals of VWP countries who are also nationals of Iraq, Syria,    Iran, or Sudan.
>
> These restrictions do not apply to VWP travelers whose presence in
>   Iraq, Syria, Iran, Sudan, Libya, Somalia, or Yemen was to perform
>   military service in the armed forces of a program country, or in order
>   to carry out official duties as a full-time employee of the government
>   of a program country.  We recommend those individuals who have
>   traveled to one or more of the seven countries listed above for
>   military/official purposes bring with them appropriate documentation
>   when traveling through a U.S. port of entry.  However, these
>   exceptions do not apply to the restriction for dual nationals of one
>   of the subject countries (“dual national restriction”).
>
> The vast majority of VWP-eligible travelers will not be affected by
>   the new Act. New countries may be added to this list by designation of
>   the Secretary of Homeland Security.